# Пункты без текста в spinner

Tags: android, kotlin, android-spinner

Заполняю spinner из адаптера `sqlite`

```
var adapter1 = SimpleCursorAdapter(context, R.layout.item, result, arrayOf("BRANCHES_NAME"), intArrayOf(R.id.text1),0)
adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter1)
```

При заполнении виден текст выбранного элемента только в скрытом состоянии.
В раскрытом пункты есть, но они не подписаны, пустые пункты.

Xml layout item

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/text1"
style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
android:singleLine="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:textAlignment="inherit"/>
```

Адаптер стандартный, SimpleCursorAdapter, не менял

```
public SimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from,
            int[] to, int flags) {
        super(context, layout, c, flags);
        mTo = to;
        mOriginalFrom = from;
        findColumns(c, from);
    }
```

Не совсем понимаю как работает адаптер. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: покажите код адаптера пожалуйста

Comment: Код адаптера не менял, это стандартный SimpleCursorAdapter

Comment: попробуйте убрать `android:textAlignment="inherit"` может текст где-то и есть, но не там где нужно

Comment: У вас разные идентификаторы для свернутого и выпадающего элементов. SimpleCursorAdapter заполняет только тот, что вы указали.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы используете вот это для выпадающего списка

```
android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item
```

То вот это `intArrayOf(R.id.text1)` не является корректным идентификатором.

**Как надо.**
Используйте системный идентификатор везде, если используете системные ресурсы.

`intArrayOf(android.R.id.text1)` и `android:id="@android:id/text1"` в собственном xml.